# How to Fetch "Avg. Time on Screen" from Firebase Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Tried below Query it is executing in bigquery but no result delivered.  How to fetch the Avg.Time on Screen. Pls. Help

```
   select    event_name,  
param1.value.string_value as firebase_previous_screen,   
param2.value.int_value as engagement_time_msec, 
param3.value.string_value as firebase_screen,count(*) as screen_views,
count( distinct user_pseudo_id ) as uniqueusers,
From `<Table>`,
UNNEST(event_params) as param1,
UNNEST(event_params) as param2,
UNNEST(event_params) as param3
where _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20220322'  AND '20220323' 
and event_name = 'user_engagement' 
and param1.key='firebase_previous_screen' and
param2.key='engagement_time_msec'  and
param3.key='firebase_screen'
group by 1, 2, 3 ,4 order by
engagement_time_msec desc
```

@ewertonvsilva For your Query Shared. I am getting below error. Pls. find below the screenshot for your kind reference. Pls. help

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the sample data of the table you are querying and sample output you want to achieve so I can reproduce t.

Comment: Thanks @ewertonvsilva for your response. As mentioned, shared the existing query output and expected output in the post. Requesting your help.

Comment: @Ramakrishnan M. You should provide mock-up input and output data you want to get when executing the above script. I see that the answer below tries to achieve but it's no help if you can't provide additional details.

Comment: @Ramakrishnan M.,  When you are using `avg` you should put the column you want the average data. It must exist on the table you are querying.  Here is the link for [avg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#avg) documentation page for further information on the function usage.